# Trouble displaying Native Ads in Mobile Web in AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook-audience-network

In my AngularJS application I am attempting to add a Facebook Native Web Ad to one of my views. I followed the steps outlined [in the documentation](http://Display%20Native%20Ads%20in%20Mobile%20Web) to generate the necessary HTML snippet and added this to my view.

My application is using ui-router to resolve routes. When visiting the route/view containing this code snippet the FB ad is not displayed and neither of the callbacks are invoked (onAdLoaded or onAdError).

**Facebook Generated HTML Snippet (added to view):**

```
<div style="display:none; position: relative;">
    <iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
            placementid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx',
            format: 'native',
            testmode: true,
            onAdLoaded: function (element) {
                console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
                element.style.display = 'block';
            },
            onAdError: function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
                console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
            }
        };
        (function (w, l, d, t) {
            var a = t();
            var b = d.currentScript || (function () {
                        var c = d.getElementsByTagName('script');
                        return c[c.length - 1];
                    })();
            var e = b.parentElement;
            e.dataset.placementid = data.placementid;
            var f = function (v) {
                try {
                    return v.document.referrer;
                } catch (e) {
                }
                return '';
            };
            var g = function (h) {
                var i = h.indexOf('/', h.indexOf('://') + 3);
                if (i === -1) {
                    return h;
                }
                return h.substring(0, i);
            };
            var j = [l.href];
            var k = false;
            var m = false;
            if (w !== w.parent) {
                var n;
                var o = w;
                while (o !== n) {
                    var h;
                    try {
                        m = m || (o.$sf && o.$sf.ext);
                        h = o.location.href;
                    } catch (e) {
                        k = true;
                    }
                    j.push(h || f(n));
                    n = o;
                    o = o.parent;
                }
            }
            var p = l.ancestorOrigins;
            if (p) {
                if (p.length > 0) {
                    data.domain = p[p.length - 1];
                } else {
                    data.domain = g(j[j.length - 1]);
                }
            }
            data.url = j[j.length - 1];
            data.channel = g(j[0]);
            data.width = screen.width;
            data.height = screen.height;
            data.pixelratio = w.devicePixelRatio;
            data.placementindex = w.ADNW && w.ADNW.Ads ? w.ADNW.Ads.length : 0;
            data.crossdomain = k;
            data.safeframe = !!m;
            var q = {};
            q.iframe = e.firstElementChild;
            var r = 'https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.3';
            for (var s in data) {
                q[s] = data[s];
                if (typeof(data[s]) !== 'function') {
                    r += '&' + s + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[s]);
                }
            }
            q.iframe.src = r;
            q.tagJsInitTime = a;
            q.rootElement = e;
            q.events = [];
            w.addEventListener('message', function (u) {
                if (u.source !== q.iframe.contentWindow) {
                    return;
                }
                u.data.receivedTimestamp = t();
                if (this.sdkEventHandler) {
                    this.sdkEventHandler(u.data);
                } else {
                    this.events.push(u.data);
                }
            }.bind(q), false);
            q.tagJsIframeAppendedTime = t();
            w.ADNW = w.ADNW || {};
            w.ADNW.Ads = w.ADNW.Ads || [];
            w.ADNW.Ads.push(q);
            w.ADNW.init && w.ADNW.init(q);
        })(window, location, document, Date.now || function () {
                    return +new Date;
                });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbadnw.js" async></script>
    <style>
        .thirdPartyRoot {
            background-color: white;
            color: #444;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-left: 0;
            border-right: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 16px;
            width: 320px;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
        }

        .thirdPartyMediaClass {
            width: 320px;
            height: 168px;
            margin: 12px 0;
        }

        .thirdPartySubtitleClass {
            font-size: 18px;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: -webkit-box;
            height: 16px;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        }

        .thirdPartyTitleClass {
            padding-right: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: -webkit-box;
            height: 36px;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        }

        .thirdPartyCallToActionClass {
            background-color: #416BC4;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 4px;
            padding: 6px 20px;
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .fbDefaultNativeAdWrapper {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 14px;
            margin: 12px 0;
            height: 36px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="thirdPartyRoot">
        <a class="fbAdLink">
            <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
            <div class="fbAdSubtitle thirdPartySubtitleClass"></div>
            <div class="fbDefaultNativeAdWrapper">
                <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
                <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I noticed that the Facebook Audience Network JS is loaded asynchronously and suspected that I might have a race condition causing the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbadnw.js" async></script>
```

To test this, I've moved the FB code snippet out of my view and into my SPA index.html. The ad appears as expected. What callback does the **fbadnw.js** script call once the script is loaded? Is the closure within the FB generated code being invoked before **fbadnw.js** is loaded perhaps?

**index.html (works)**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="kcl-app">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- ui-router view -->
    <div ui-view></div>

 <!-- FB Begin -->
    <div class="fb-native">
        <div style="display:none; position: relative;">
            <iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var data = {
                    placementid: 'xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxx',
                    format: 'native',
                    testmode: true,
                    onAdLoaded: function (element) {
                        console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
                        element.style.display = 'block';
                    },
                    onAdError: function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
                        console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
                    }
                };
                (function (w, l, d, t) {
                    var a = t();
                    var b = d.currentScript || (function () {
                                var c = d.getElementsByTagName('script');
                                return c[c.length - 1];
                            })();
                    var e = b.parentElement;
                    e.dataset.placementid = data.placementid;
                    var f = function (v) {
                        try {
                            return v.document.referrer;
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                        return '';
                    };
                    var g = function (h) {
                        var i = h.indexOf('/', h.indexOf('://') + 3);
                        if (i === -1) {
                            return h;
                        }
                        return h.substring(0, i);
                    };
                    var j = [l.href];
                    var k = false;
                    var m = false;
                    if (w !== w.parent) {
                        var n;
                        var o = w;
                        while (o !== n) {
                            var h;
                            try {
                                m = m || (o.$sf && o.$sf.ext);
                                h = o.location.href;
                            } catch (e) {
                                k = true;
                            }
                            j.push(h || f(n));
                            n = o;
                            o = o.parent;
                        }
                    }
                    var p = l.ancestorOrigins;
                    if (p) {
                        if (p.length > 0) {
                            data.domain = p[p.length - 1];
                        } else {
                            data.domain = g(j[j.length - 1]);
                        }
                    }
                    data.url = j[j.length - 1];
                    data.channel = g(j[0]);
                    data.width = screen.width;
                    data.height = screen.height;
                    data.pixelratio = w.devicePixelRatio;
                    data.placementindex = w.ADNW && w.ADNW.Ads ? w.ADNW.Ads.length : 0;
                    data.crossdomain = k;
                    data.safeframe = !!m;
                    var q = {};
                    q.iframe = e.firstElementChild;
                    var r = 'https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/web/?sdk=5.3';
                    for (var s in data) {
                        q[s] = data[s];
                        if (typeof(data[s]) !== 'function') {
                            r += '&' + s + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[s]);
                        }
                    }
                    q.iframe.src = r;
                    q.tagJsInitTime = a;
                    q.rootElement = e;
                    q.events = [];
                    w.addEventListener('message', function (u) {
                        if (u.source !== q.iframe.contentWindow) {
                            return;
                        }
                        u.data.receivedTimestamp = t();
                        if (this.sdkEventHandler) {
                            this.sdkEventHandler(u.data);
                        } else {
                            this.events.push(u.data);
                        }
                    }.bind(q), false);
                    q.tagJsIframeAppendedTime = t();
                    w.ADNW = w.ADNW || {};
                    w.ADNW.Ads = w.ADNW.Ads || [];
                    w.ADNW.Ads.push(q);
                    w.ADNW.init && w.ADNW.init(q);
                })(window, location, document, Date.now || function () {
                            return +new Date;
                        });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbadnw.js" async></script>
            <style>
                .thirdPartyRoot {
                    background-color: white;
                    color: #444;
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                    border-left: 0;
                    border-right: 0;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 16px;
                    width: 320px;
                    text-align: left;
                    position: relative;
                }

                .thirdPartyMediaClass {
                    width: 320px;
                    height: 168px;
                    margin: 12px 0;
                }

                .thirdPartySubtitleClass {
                    font-size: 18px;
                    -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    height: 16px;
                    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                }

                .thirdPartyTitleClass {
                    padding-right: 12px;
                    line-height: 18px;
                    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    display: -webkit-box;
                    height: 36px;
                    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
                }

                .thirdPartyCallToActionClass {
                    background-color: #416BC4;
                    color: white;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    padding: 6px 20px;
                    float: right;
                    text-align: center;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size: 11px;
                }

                .fbDefaultNativeAdWrapper {
                    font-size: 12px;
                    line-height: 14px;
                    margin: 12px 0;
                    height: 36px;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }
            </style>
            <div class="thirdPartyRoot">
                <a class="fbAdLink">
                    <div class="fbAdMedia thirdPartyMediaClass"></div>
                    <div class="fbAdSubtitle thirdPartySubtitleClass"></div>
                    <div class="fbDefaultNativeAdWrapper">
                        <div class="fbAdCallToAction thirdPartyCallToActionClass"></div>
                        <div class="fbAdTitle thirdPartyTitleClass"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FB End -->


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: First try to get rid of the async attribute. It might be a simple fix. If you don't want to try that you can use ocLazyload to load the js before the route is resolved (with `resolve` param in state definition).

Comment: @MuliYulzary so ocLazyload can wrap an external script and return a promise? I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by editing the boilerplate code provided by FB. In a nutshell, the provided closure (minified) attempts to:

1. Locate the iframe element where the Ad will be rendered and set it's
   src and other attributes.
2. Attach an event handler to listen for post messages "message".
3. Initialize the Ad with FB Audience Network (ADNW.init())

My problem was with the assumptions this code makes in Step 1.

```
var b = d.currentScript || (function() {
    var c = d.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return c[c.length - 1];
})();
var e = b.parentElement;
```

The above code is attempting to locate this DIV.

```
<div style="display:none; position: relative;">
```

It does this by first trying to locate the parent of the **last script element on the page**. This is brittle and, in my case, did not work. The last script element added in my document was not the one this code expected.

I modified this code to explicitly select the correct element by ID.

Added an ID to containing DIV:

```
<div id="fb-ad-container" style="display:none; position: relative;">
```

Simplify the DOM parsing code (step 1) to select this DIV by ID:

```
 var e = d.getElementById("fb-ad-container");
```

By selecting the correct element by ID I was able to alleviate the need to locate the current script element. The rest of the script ran as expected.